# Which property will make overflow-wrap to stop working?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fit a paragraph inside a div block, but it happens that the div block is inside another structure of html and css. I'm using `overflow-wrap: break-word;` inside the `div` and by definition the span containing the text should inherit and apply the property, but it is not working.

So I think there is another property among the ancestors that is stopping the property to work, but I cannot imagine which one.

It is something like

```
...
<div style="width: 200px; overflow-wrap: break-word; border: 1px solid blue"> 
<span> {{text}} </span>
</div>
...
```

The `overflow-wrap` property is not working and it is being not overwritten as the developer tools says so

Comment: Impossible to say without you posting a [mcve] in your question

Comment: Your example seems to work fine.

Comment: The example works fine, the thing is that it is inside of another structure of html and css and for some reason it is not working there @abney317

Comment: No way of know what is wrong without reproducing the issue for us here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with this behavior I have found that the property `white-space:nowrap` was set on one of the ancestors of the div, so the `white-space: normal` was overriden, that's why the text were not fitting inside the div